# Ftp : Unable to connect to remote server exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a website that I use to upload files (excel) to the server and it eventually uploads them to an FTP site from the server.I not able to upload the file to ftp. Getting error. I am able to upload file to my local system.

```
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file_Uploader, FormCollection formcoll)
{
    try
    {
        string fileName = string.Empty; string filePath = string.Empty;
        filePath = file_Uploader.FileName;
        fileName = Path.GetFileName(file_Uploader.FileName);
        string ftpAddress = "10.99.248.83"; //string ftpAddress = "D://";
        string username = "prashant.rathod"; string password = "********";

        using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader("" + filePath))
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(stream.ReadToEnd());

            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://" + ftpAddress + "/" + "rs/Files" + "/" + fileName);                 
            //WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(ftpAddress + "/" + "Work" + "/" + fileName);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            request.Proxy = null;
            Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            reqStream.Close();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I am also getting an error: `User failed to provide the error message`

Answer (score 0):

```
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

I'm thinking that, if you actually print out the exception here, such as with:

```
Debug.Writeline(ex.ToString());
```

it may tell you *exactly* what the problem is. It's almost always a bad idea to catch exceptions then ignore them.

If you *do* get a decent error message, you need to examine what it's telling you. The ability to upload to your local box in no way guarantees being able to upload to some other arbitrary box.

Probably the *first* thing I would try would be to attempt connecting to the problematic server with another tool, such as a proven FTP client. That will isolate the problem to either the server or your code.

Comment: No, OP states they're getting an error. I can only gather that, because they didn't tell _us_ what the error was, the information isn't available. Hence the answer. If any of those methods within try/catch raise an exception, it'll be invisible.

Comment: I am getting exception "Unable to connect to remote server exception"

Comment: @Prashant, I find that a little difficult to believe when you're throwing away exceptions.

Comment: added debug and got this "Unable to connect to the remote server" ex.StackTrace : at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()

Comment: @Prashant, and what happens when you try to FTP to that site manually (such as with your favourite FTP client)?

Comment: I tried manually then also its giving error like "The remote server returned an error: (534) 534 Policy requires SSL."

Comment: I got the solution, not giving permission in SSL. Now its working. And thank you for your time.